# Tag all English words in text files with @s:eng only on lines starting with *CHI:

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write a Python script to tag all English words only on lines that start with *CHI: with "@s:eng" at the end of the word but the code does not seem to work. Currently, the code looks like this:

```
import re

with open("transcript 0623.cha", encoding='utf8') as f:

    text = f.read()

    new_text = re.sub("A-Za-z", "A-Za-z@s:eng", text)
    with open("transcript 0623_out.cha", "w", encoding='utf8') as result:
        result.write(new_text)
```

Can you suggest how I can improve the code?

The sample contents of transcript 0623 are as follows:

```
@Begin
@Languages: zho , eng
@Participants:  TEA Teacher , CHI Child
@ID:    zho,|change_me_later|TEA|||||Teacher|||
@ID:    zho,|change_me_later|CHI|||||Child|||
@Transcriber:   CKX
@Activities:    Storytelling
@Comment:   child used the malay word sayang
*TEA:   ok ,   来   ,   开始   .
*CHI:   呃   ,   the   boy@s   .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   have a frog@s .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   ok do you know what is boy in chinese ?
*TEA:   can you help me tell the story in chinese ?
*TEA:   ok then do you know what is a frog in chinese ?
*TEA:   ok , come .
*TEA:   go to the next page .
*CHI:   when the boy sleeping , then the frog come out@s .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   还有 吗   ?
*CHI:   the cat also sleeping@s .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   do you know what is cat in chinese ?
*TEA:   嗯   ,   what   is   it   ?
*CHI:   猫   .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   so can you use your chinese for cat to help me tell the story ?
*TEA:   嗯   ?
*CHI:   猫   睡觉   .
*TEA:   啊   ,   很   好   .
*TEA:   还有   吗   ?
*CHI:   frog come out@s .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   很   好   .
*TEA:   还有   吗   ?
*CHI:   next one@s .
*TEA:   ok .
*CHI:   the boy wake up@s .
*CHI:   and , the frog is gone@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   then , maybe , the frog went out the window@s .
*TEA:   嗯   ,   ok   .
*CHI:   the boy is looking for the frog@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   the cat is looking for the frog@s .
*TEA:   ok   what   is   cat   in   chinese   again   ?
*CHI:   what@s ?
*TEA:   what is cat in chinese again ?
*CHI:   猫   .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*TEA:   ok can you use the chinese word for cat to tell me the story again ?
*TEA:   嗯   ?
*CHI:   猫   looking   for   the@s   .
*TEA:   啊   .
*CHI:   for the@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   frog@s .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   very good .
*TEA:   anything else ?
*TEA:   ok .
*CHI:   the@s   猫   go   in@s   .
*CHI:   and put the bottle in here@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   the boy has do this@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   the cat fall down@s .
*TEA:   ok   what   is   cat   in   chinese   again   ?
*CHI:   猫   fall   down@s   .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   and get the bottle@s .
*CHI:   get the bottle@s .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   very good .
*TEA:   ok anything else ?
*TEA:   anything else ?
*TEA:   ok .
*CHI:   the   boy   go   and   sayang   the   cat@s   .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*TEA:   what is cat in chinese ?
*CHI:   the , the boy go and sayang the@s 猫 .
*TEA:   啊   ,   ok   .
*TEA:   very good .
*CHI:   and then the bottle break@s .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   very good .
*TEA:   anything else ?
*TEA:   come .
*TEA:   ok this whole thing is together .
*CHI:   the boy is calling for the frog@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   the cat is looking underneath the table@s .
*TEA:   ok   what   is   cat   in   chinese   again   ?
*CHI:   the@s 猫 looking for the frog underneath@s .
*TEA:   嗯   ,   ok   .
*CHI:   they looking inside the hole if the frog is here@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*TEA:   anything else ?
*CHI:   then the boy is here@s .
*TEA:   啊 , ok very good .
*TEA:   anything else ?
*CHI:   the boy fall down into the water@s .
*CHI:   and the cat also@s .
*CHI:   and then the log break@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*TEA:   do you know what is water in chinese ?
*TEA:   what is it ?
*CHI:   水   .
*TEA:   ok can you tell me the story again with the word , with the , with
    the chinese word for water ?
*TEA:   嗯   ?
*CHI:   the boy fall down@s .
*CHI:   and   the@s   猫   too@s   .
*CHI:   and   both   of   them   fall   in   the@s   水   .
*TEA:   ok , very good .
*CHI:   and then they all get wet@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*TEA:   ok .
*CHI:   they found some water on the log@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   they found so many frogs@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   and is this the frog that they have@s ?
*TEA:   嗯   .
*TEA:   ok .
*CHI:   then they say bye bye .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*TEA:   you know how to say bye bye in chinese ?
*CHI:   再见   .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   can you repeat this part again in chinese ?
*CHI:   and   then   the   boy   and   the   cat   and   the   frog
    say@s   再见   .
*TEA:   ok   what   is   cat   in   chinese   again   ?
*CHI:   猫   .
*TEA:   啊   .
*TEA:   can you repeat the whole thing ?
*CHI:   the boy and the@s 猫 and the , and the frog@s .
*TEA:   嗯   .
*CHI:   say@s   再见   .
*TEA:   ok .
*TEA:   very good .
*TEA:   thank you for telling me the story ok ?
@End
```

Comment: Your code never mentions `*CHI`, why would it work? `A-Za-z` will match _exactly one_ uppercase or lowercase latin character

Comment: Please provide sample contents of _transcript 0623.cha_.

Comment: updated first post with contents of transcript 0623.cha

Comment: What is the expected output? For example, does " _*CHI:   呃   ,   the   boy@s   ._ " become " _*CHI:   呃   ,   the   boy@s   .@s:eng_ " or " _*CHI:   呃   ,   the   boy@s:eng   ._ " or what..?

Comment: The expected output would be " *CHI: 呃 , the@s:eng boy@s:eng " which means that every English words in lines starting with *CHI are tagged with @s:eng. Another example of an expected output would be " *CHI:    the@s:eng cat@s:eng is@s:eng looking@s:eng underneath@s:eng the@s:eng table@s:eng"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect:

> ```
> new_text = re.sub("A-Za-z", "A-Za-z@s:eng", text)
> ```

The search pattern is looking for "*uppercase A, hyphen, uppercase Z, lowercase a, hyphen, lowercase z*". If you wanted to only check lines that "*that start with *CHI:*" then "**CHI:*" should be part of your search pattern.

The replacement pattern replaces the entire line with just "*A-Za-z@s:eng*". You need to capture the parts of the text that you want to retain and then reuse them appending "*@s:eng" at the end of the word*".

Here's something you can use:

```py
import re

i_path = "transcript 0623.cha"
o_path = "transcript 0623_out.cha"
mark_pattern = re.compile("\\*CHI:.*")
word_pattern = re.compile("([A-Za-z]+)")

with open(i_path, encoding='utf8') as i_file, open(o_path, "w", encoding='utf8') as o_file:
    for line in i_file:
        # Split into possible words
        parts = line.split()

        if mark_pattern.match(parts[0]) is None:
            o_file.write(line)
            continue

        # Got a CHI line
        new_line = line
        for word in parts[1:]:
            matches = word_pattern.match(word)
            if matches:
                old = f"\\b{word}\\b"
                new = f"{matches.group(1)}@s:eng"
                new_line = re.sub(old, new, new_line, count=1)
        o_file.write(new_line)
```

**Explanation:**

- `mark_pattern = re.compile("\\*CHI:.*")`

  - Pattern for matching lines that start with " **CHI:* * ". You need to escape the `*` at the start because [`*` is a special character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).
  - The `re` docs says that "*using [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) and saving the resulting regular expression object for reuse is more efficient when the expression will be used several times in a single program.*"
- `word_pattern = re.compile("([A-Za-z]+)")`

  - Pattern for matching words. You need to use `[]` to indicate a set of characters and then `+` to indicate matching 1 or more repetitions of the preceding pattern.
- `for line in i_file`

  - It will be easier (and more memory efficient) to process the file line-by-line. You can easily debug the regex search-and-replace per line. Maybe it's possible to do all this in one `read()`/`readlines()` but here I'm preferring readability.
- `parts = line.split()`

  - To look for words, split the line into possible words.
- `.match(..)`

  - See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match
  - It returns a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) and if you have captures (`()`) in your regex pattern, you can access them in using `.group()`. This is used for changing `word` to `word@s:eng`.

First, I check if the first word (`parts[0]`) is the "CHI" pattern. If it isn't, just write the line as-is to the output file. If it is, proceed with processing by word.

For each possible word, check if it matches the word pattern. If it does, use `re.sub` to replace the old instance of the word from the line with `word@s:eng`. Repeat this match-then-replace for each word and accumulate the replacements in `new_line`. Note that, by using `matches.group(1)`, I replace the `@s` in the original line (like the one in "frog@s" becomes "frog@s:eng").

I used f-strings for the `old` and `new`. You can use regular string concatenation/formatting if you're not on Python3.6+.

**Result:**

```
I: *CHI:   have a frog@s .
O: *CHI:   have@s:eng a@s:eng frog@s:eng .

I: *CHI:   the cat is looking underneath the table@s .
O: *CHI:   the@s:eng@s:eng cat@s:eng is@s:eng looking@s:eng underneath@s:eng the table@s:eng .

(ignore punctuations)
I: *CHI:   what@s ?
O: *CHI:   what@s:eng ?

(ignore non-English words in lines)
I: *CHI:   猫   fall   down@s   .
O: *CHI:   猫   fall@s:eng   down@s:eng   .

(unaffected if not starts with CHI)
I: *TEA:   ok this whole thing is together .
O: *TEA:   ok this whole thing is together .
```

Comment: Dear Gino, thank you for the suggestion and explanation. When I applied the code to the text file, the resultant output is a blank text file. Do you think that I could have run it wrongly?

Comment: @TohAn Hmm there is no special way to run it, just `python3 myscript.py` (or whatever the name of your script is). I'm running it OK on Ubuntu18 and macOS 10.13.6, both using Python3.7.5. If you have an existing _transcript 0623_out.cha_, delete it so that the script will create a new one (and make sure it's not opened anywhere else when you run the script). You can also try removing the space from the filenames in `i_path` and `o_path`.

Comment: Dear Gino, thank you for the prompt reply and suggestions! It works now.

Comment: Dear Gino, currently, I am trying to modify the code to apply to multiple text files in the same directory. The code is updated in the first post but there is an error "NameError: name 'output' is not defined". Can you help me to suggest improvements to the code?

Comment: @TohAn If you have a **new** question, post it as a **separate, new** question. Don't update the original question because the Answers section and the comments will become confusing. Stack Overflow's format is 1 Question, 1 Answer.

Comment: @TohAn "_It works now._" Great. Consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry about that, and I will post in a new question.